# getting data out of selection listener java

Tags: java, swt, listener

I am building a Graphical User Interface, and used a [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to pick up the file the user choose, so everything works fine, but now i am trying to get the path of the file selected (made quite easily through a `file.getAbsolutePath()`).

But somehow i can't get it out of the class... i want to have a String path in the class with the listener, which looks like this :

```
private void browseButton(Canvas BasicSelection)
{
    final Button btnBrowse = new Button(BasicSelection, SWT.NONE);
    btnBrowse.setBounds(70, 29, 68, 23);
    btnBrowse.setText("Browse");
    btnBrowse.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
    {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
        {
            filechooser.createAndShowGUI(path);
            sbtnBrowse = btnBrowse.getSelection();
        }
    });
    launchEvent();
}
```

And here is the action performed when the button is clicked :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    //Set up the file chooser.
    if (fc == null)
    {
        fc = new JFileChooser();
    }
    fc.addChoosableFileFilter(new Filter());
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    //Show it.
    int returnVal = fc.showDialog(FileChooser.this,"Attach");

    //Process the results.
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
    {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        setPath(file);
        log.append("Attaching file: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
        // Here is where i would need to get the file... but how ?
    } 
    else 
    {
        log.append("Attachment cancelled by user." + newline);
    }
    log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

    //Reset the file chooser for the next time it's shown.
    fc.setSelectedFile(null);
}
```

How can i get the file name out of the class ?

EDIT : I already tried with getters and setters but strangely he tried to access the content before i actuallt wrote in it.

```
String path ;
/*
 Rest of the code ...
*/
public void setPath(File input)
{
    if (input != null)
    {
        this.path = input.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("path is now set correctly : ");
    }
}
public String getPath()
{
    return this.path;
}
```

Comment: If possible, try to *not* mix SWT and Swing, there is a [`FileDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FFileDialog.html) in SWT which you can use. To your question: Create getter and setter methods or use a `static` `String` variable to store the path...

Comment: @Baz So you mean i should use the FileDialog **instead** of the JFilechooser, right?
Yeah i tried using getter and setter, i did put a String path in my class, but the problem was, when i tried to access it from the outside, the path was null (he wanted to access the path before i had choosed the file). And i don't know how to solve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that should do exactly what you are asking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Select file");

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            /* Create the dialog */
            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);

            /* Open it. The absolute path of the selected file will be saved in the String variable */
            String selection = dialog.open();

            /* If the user selected something, print it */
            if(selection != null)
                System.out.println(selection);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Oo yeah thanks ! That's pretty much everything i need, but how can i get the absolut path, now that i don't use the file type anymore? 
I didn't found what i wanted [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FFileDialog.html) .

Comment: @trolologuy The variable `selection` contains the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing that `JFileChooser` itself does -- declare an instance variable `private String fileChosen` (within the class, outside any methods), set it with the path obtained, and call a method on this class to obtain it (`getSelectedFile()` does this for `JFileChooser`).

Comment: yeah i already tried this with : 
`    public void setPath(File input)
     {
     if (input != null)
     {
      this.path = input.getAbsolutePath();
         System.out.println("path is now set correctly : ");
     }
    }
    public String getPath()
    {
  return this.path;
    }`
But the problem is when i try to access it from the outside, he tries to access it before i actually wrote in it.